# what is lastModTime for a OOZIE workflow?

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

When I talk to the OOZIE rest API about a specific workflow,

```
curl "http://[OOZIE_URL]/oozie/v1/job/7039276-181005225000195-oozie-oozi-W?show=info&time=GMT"
```

I get a response like this,

```
...
'createdTime': 'Fri, 19 Oct 2018 05:12:26 GMT',
'endTime': None,
'externalId': None,
'group': None,
'id': '7039276-181005225000195-oozie-oozi-W',
'lastModTime': 'Fri, 19 Oct 2018 21:15:01 GMT',
'parentId': '7024011-181005225000195-oozie-oozi-C@4',
'run': 1,
'startTime': 'Fri, 19 Oct 2018 17:56:07 GMT',
'status': 'RUNNING',
'toString': 'Workflow id[7039276-181005225000195-oozie-oozi-W] '
         'status[RUNNING]',
```

Does anyone know what exactly is this 'lastModTime'?

I want to monitor my jobs that run today, and I'm not sure if 'lastModTime' is the correct field to use for this purpose.